# Selenium Webdriver C# wait for existence when using PageFactory

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to click an okay button which might appear after completing a field - it might take 5 seconds to appear. So i need (if) Wait for existence 5 seconds. I'm using PageFactory in a pages framework, I've seen some solutions but cant figure out how to implement them in this context.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "OK")]
private IWebElement alertOKBtn;

public void PopulateFields //method to populate the form
{
   // Populate fields
   dateFromField.SendKeys(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
   // Click on this field
   descriptionField.Click();

   //OK button might appear, might take 5secs - pseudcode
   if ( ***alertOKBtn exists, wait for it for 5 secs..*** )
   {
     alertOkBtn.Click();
   }

   //continue populating form

   }
```

The PopulateFields method is called from the [Test] as:-

Pages.PTW.PopulateFields();

where Pages.PTW is a get method to PageFactory.InitElements(browser.Driver, page); return page;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add conditional wait. That means, your code should wait till the control appears and then perform the action.

WebDriverWait class which inherits DefaultWait class serves the purpose. The below is the code snippet.

```
 var wait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, waitTime);
 wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(alertOkBtn));
 alertOkBtn.Click();
```

Comment: Thanks! - the **this.driver** isn't recognised "does not contained a definition for driver and no extension method..." I've added a bit more code on how PopulateFields is called by the [TestFixture] - sorry its my lack of understanding of c# OO. Not sure how to recognised this.driver in that class?

Comment: Also - the alertOkBtn  might **not** appear - so the test would need to move on **without** doing the alertOkBtn.Click(); if this happens.

Comment: I am glad you were able to resolve the issue. this.driver in my case is browser in your case.
Also try to have the method return Boolean instead of string and have the code as 
if(waittosee)
{
//your logic
}

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resolve it - in PopulateFields i now do this:-

```
          //wait to see if alert popup appears - give it 8 secs
        string waitToSee = browser.wait(alertOKBtn, 8);

        if ( waitToSee == "true" )
        {
            alertOKBtn.Click(); //alert popup did appear

        }
```

Then I've added a method to my browser.class :-

```
    public static string wait(IWebElement elem, int timeout  ) //waits for existence of element up to timeout amount
    {
        try 
        {
            var wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(elem));
            return "true";
        }
        catch (Exception e ) //didnt appear so exception thrown return false

        {
            return "false";
        }
```

So it now waits up to 8 seconds and if it doesnt appear it ignores and moves on. Thanks Bendram for the pointers.